# Hadoop dies on ld-linux.so

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I have the following setup:

- Hadoop 1.2.1
- Oracle Java 1.7
- Suse Enterprise Server 10 32bit

If I execute the Pi-example in standalone mode with

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 10 10
```

then Java dies the hard way, telling me

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0xb7efa20b, pid=9494, tid=3070639008
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux.so.2+0x920b]  do_lookup_x+0xab
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/hadoop-1.2.1-new/hs_err_pid9494.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

(The full trace is [here](http://pastie.org/8338480))

On a distributed setup, i can `start-all` components and they are ideling fine. But when I submit a job, then the jobtracker dies immediately with an `java.io.EOFException`, I assume this is due to the same error as above.

I have already tried the same hadoop on another computer, there everything is fine (altough this one runs Arch Linux 64bit), and other Javas (OpenJDK, 1.6, 1.7) don't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Hadoop includes a native library that was either compiled for a different platform (e.g. 64 bit instead of 32 bit), or the library expects a different environment. The stack trace also shows that `JVM_LoadLibrary()` is trying to load a native lib.

Make sure you downloaded the correct version of Hadoop for your platform, or compile it yourself for your target platform.

Comment: I also thought of that, but since neither the downloaded filename nor the instructions on the hadoop website said something about 64bit, I assumed there was something else wrong.
Building it then solved the problem -- thank you.